# Is it possible to have multiple touch gesture combinations unlock a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, gesture

I want to create a hidden part of my game that is triggered by doing a series of touches and swipes on the game over screen.  Kind of like the old Nintendo style unlocks but with iPhones & iPads.

I want a pattern like this to unlock the secret level. Swipe down, swipe down, swipe up, swipe down, swipe right, swipe left, two finger long press.  Is something like this possible and if so, how would I go about it?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried?

Comment: Usually I would post code, but I'm new to Objective-C so I didn't know where to start with code on this one since I'm not even sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can register several different gesture recognizers, and then, as they are triggered by the user's actions, track the sequence and if/when it matches your "secret" pattern, invoke the view controller for your hidden section.

To track the swipe/touch sequence (assuming the sequence is always the same), just have an instance variable which holds the next expected event. e.g. initially you are expecting a SWIPE-DOWN.

When you get an event, if it is the expected event, then advance to the next one e.g SWIPE-UP.  If it is wrong, then reset the expected event to its initial state.

If you get all the events in the right order, then you unlock the hidden view.

Comment: So in Storyboards, I would drop in all of the gesture recognizers to my View Controller?  How would I go about making sure the right order is captured?

Comment: One way to accomplish this would be to create an array with the proper order, and an instance variable to capture the number of taps, and in the gesture recognizers, compare the number of touches to the index in the array.